# Matlab accessing structures

Tags: matlab, indexing, struct

I am trying to access data that are stored in structures in matlab. Having many files I am trying to make the process automatic, however I have a problem in accessing the struct using the structure name (given that it is a string). Also, storing the structure in a variable (as shown below) does not work either, because matlab attaches the whole structure to the variable. Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

```
%Initialize variables
Data_Struct = load(dirData(1).name);
file_id = fieldnames(Data_Struct);
data = Data_Struct.Trajectories;
```

Here a screenshot of the struct containing the data 
[image]

Comment: Can you upload one test case, or the screenshot of how the data is organized in the struct?

Comment: sure, I just edited the question

Comment: What's inside the Trajectories? If another struct called 'Labeled', then what's inside of this?

Comment: Yes inside Trajectories, there is another structure called Labelled, and then a matrix of data

Comment: data = Data_Struct.Trajectories.Labelled.(name of the data matrix)

This will provide the data matrix as a variable.

Comment: That does not work. As you can see in the screenshot, there is a structure in between (in that case ASR_B10_Ctrl_OFF) that is the ID of the file. Given that I have many of these files I was trying to find a way to make this more general

Answer (score 2):

The file name is changing every time so you need to get the it correctly when loading a new struct.

```
Data_Struct = load(dirData(1).name);
```

After this line,

```
name = fieldnames(Data_Struct);
```

This will give you the unique name of your file. Finally,

```
data = Data_Struct.(name{1}).Trajectories.Labelled.(name of the data matrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to exploit the fact that you can acces to a structure field by its name string as:

```
name = 'Trajectories'
value = Data_Struct.(name)
```

So, in your case, to get unrolled values as Cell Array you can use:

```
%%Little example copying some of your structure
Data_Struct.Trajectories.Labelled = zeros(10);
Data_Struct.Analog = zeros(10);
Data_Struct.FrameRate = 300;

[UnrolledCell] = getUnrolledVal(Data_Struct,[]);
display(UnrolledCell)
```

UnrolledCell =

3×2 cell array

```
'Labelled'     [10×10 double]
'FrameRate'    [         300]
'Analog'       [10×10 double]
```

Here the getUnrolledVal function is simply:

```
function [UnrolledCell] = getUnrolledVal(struct_in,UnrolledCell)
fields_list = fieldnames(struct_in);
for i=1:length(fields_list)
    field = fields_list{i};
    if isstruct(struct_in.(field))
        UnrolledCell = getUnrolledVal(struct_in.(field),UnrolledCell);
    else
        UnrolledCell = [UnrolledCell; {field} {struct_in.(field)}];
    end
end

end
```